# vue3 array push not woking

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
const myArray =[];

const nestedMenuitems = ref([

    {
        items:myArray 
    },
  
]);

onMounted(() => {
    ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
        stores.value = data;
        stores.value.map(function(value, _key) {
            
            myArray.push({lable: value.shop});
    
   });
   
    });
    
});
```

i am trying show array data  items:myArray this line

under the code working fine but mu custom data api to pass data its not working.what is the problem.
how to solve this?

```
const list= [
            {
                label: 'Tracker',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-compass'
            },
            {
                label: 'Map',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-map-marker'
            },
            {
                label: 'Manage',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil'
            }
        ];
const nestedMenuitems = ref([
 
    {
       
        items:list
    },
   
]);
```

i am trying show array data  items:myArray this line

under the code working fine but mu custom data api to pass data its not working.what is the problem.
how to solve this?

```
  <Menubar :model="nestedMenuitems" optionValue="value">
               
            </Menubar>
```

model="nestedMenuitems to get dropdown data

Comment: Can you show what the "Menubar" component does and what you actually want to do - so the <template> of the component would be important as well.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger reactivity you need to replace the item inside `nestedMenuItems`.

What's not clear to me is why aren't you using a simpler data structure:

```js
const state = reactive({ items: [] });
const { items } = toRefs(state);
onMounted(() => {
  ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
    data.forEach((value) => {
      state.items.push({ label: value.shop });
    });
  });
});
```

What do you need `nestedMenuItems` for? Do you have more than one `nestedMenuItem`?

You might want to show `<Menubar />`. Most likely, you don't need `v-model` in it, but `v-bind`. e.g:

```html
<Menubar :items="items" optionValue="value" />
```

---

And another question would be: if you're storing the response in `stores`, why are you also storing it somewhere else (e.g: in `nestedMenuItems`, or `items`)? Why not consume it directly from `stores`?

For example:

```js
const stores = ref([]);
const items = computed(() => stores.value.map(({ shop: label }) => ({ label })));

onMounted(() => {
  ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
    stores.value = data;
  });
});
```

```html
<pre v-text="JSON.stringify({ stores, items }, null, 2)" />
```

It's bad practice to keep the same reactive data in two separate places, because you're always running the risk of them getting out of sync. If you're using the same source, any change will be reflected in every place where the data is consumed/displayed.